# Alter datatype of column in mysql if it is not like what we want

Tags: mysql, alter

I am working on a script where I need to modify a column's datatype.
But if that column has the desired datatype then I don't want to change it.
For example if the field A is of the blob datatype then I need to change it to mediumblob.

So first I need to check if the datatype is mediumblob and if it is then there's no need to change it, otherwise change it to mediumblob.